# PowerShell script to create an Application Insights resource with type: General

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-resource-manager

Every time I try create an Application Insights resource with

> "Application_Type" = "General"

or

> "Application_Type" = "Other"

using [Azure Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/components), it is creating as `"ASP.NET"` type. It seems that the default value for `"Application_Type"` field is `"ASP.NET"` or `"Web"`.

How do I create an Application Insights resource with `"Application_Type" = "General"` using ARM template? I specifically need an Application Insight instance of General type to [collect logs from Azure AD B2C so that we can diagnose problems with our custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-troubleshoot-custom).

Answer (score 2):

The following template will work for you.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "shuitest4"
        },
        "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "other"
        },
        "hockeyAppToken": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        },
        "hockeyAppId": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        },
        "regionId": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "southcentralus"
        },
        "requestSource": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "IbizaAIExtension"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "type": "microsoft.insights/components",
            "location": "[parameters('regionId')]",
            "apiVersion": "2014-08-01",
            "properties": {
                "ApplicationId": "[parameters('name')]",
                "Application_Type": "[parameters('type')]",
                "HockeyAppToken": "[parameters('hockeyAppToken')]",
                "HockeyAppId": "[parameters('hockeyAppId')]",
                "Flow_Type": "Redfield",
                "Request_Source": "[parameters('requestSource')]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

There is a easy way for you to get the template. You could create the resource on Azure Portal, when you click `Automation options`, you will get the template.

[image]